# flutter package easyloading with ResponsiveWrapper

Tags: flutter, dart, loading

I have a problem. I'm using the easyloading package with responsivewrapper. but i can't put them together please help me

builder: EasyLoading.init(context, child) =>

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ScreenUtilInit(
    designSize: const Size(360, 690),
    minTextAdapt: true,
    splitScreenMode: true,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        builder: EasyLoading.init(context, child) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(child,
            defaultScale: true,
            breakpoints: [
              ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(480, name: MOBILE),
              ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
              ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1000, name: DESKTOP),
            ],
            background: Container(color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5))),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/': (BuildContext context) => MainPage(),
          '/CusSearchAtcp': (BuildContext context) => const CusSearchAtcp(),
        },
      );
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The builder parameter must return one widget. If you like to do initialization or return two widgets, you've to nest them yourself inside the builder:

```
builder: (context, child) {
    // do your initialization here
    child = EasyLoading.init();  // assuming this is returning a widget
    child = ResponsiveWrapper.builder(/*your required code here*/);
    return child;
  }
```

Or you should try to use 2nd way by ResponsiveWrapper.builder or EasyLoading such as:

```
builder: EasyLoading.init(builder: ResponsiveWrapper.builder(/*your required code here*/)),
```

Comment: Thank you 
I used method 2, it works by adding (builder : (context, child) =>ResponsiveWrapper.builder